# Corresponding MySQL queries of ActiveRecord queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My client wants corresponding sql queries of all ActiveRecord query which using in the application.I can able to get most from the serVer log.But queries with relations are not showing in the server or development.log file.
for eg: Student.first returning `SELECT * from students limit 1`
but Student.first.school is not returning  `SELECT * from schools where id IN ......`

Is there any way??

Comment: If there is no query in mysql queries log - then no query have been performed.

Comment: Have you enabled the full query log? Or only the slow query log?

Comment: @ypercube I didn't enabled that feature and I don't know how to do it.Are you saying through this way, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077445/how-do-i-log-just-the-raw-queries-in-mysql) please reply

Comment: @shajin: Yes, that way. Enabling the full query log (this requires restarting the MySQL deamon) will start writing all queries in that log file. It's usually not enabled because the file gets pretty big quickly. But you can have it on for a few hours so you can have all queries logged.

Comment: Thanks.It worked.You could have been wrote this on answer area.So that I can upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the full query log (this requires restarting the MySQL deamon) will start writing all queries in that log file. It's usually not enabled because the file gets pretty big quickly. But you can have it on for a few hours so you can have all queries logged.

How to enable the **General Query Log** (or full query log): [SO question: **how-do-i-log-just-the-raw-queries-in-mysql**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077445/how-do-i-log-just-the-raw-queries-in-mysql) or at: MySQL docs: [**General Query Log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

You can select where the log is saved, either to a **file** or to a **table**:

MySQL docs: [**Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-destinations.html)